# Laravel firstOrCreate y MySQL

Tags: mysql, laravel

Buen día, ojalá alguien le pase algo similar; tengo la consulta de la primera imagen, donde consulto una tabla para recuperar los datos de una persona, si no existe crea un registro con el ID de la persona y una clave aleatoria de 4 dígitos, pero al ejecutarlo no se refleja en la tabla cuando no existe el ID de la persona, por medio de clockwork revise que se ejecutara la inyección y veo la query de la 2.ª imagen, pero no se crea el registro, tomo la query la ejecute por consola y me creo el registro y como ven en la parte documentada del registro intenten crearlo por 2 formas distintas sin éxito, creo más registros en otras tablas y sin problemas. Agradecería cualquier luz a mi problema.

[image: Código]
[image: Query]

```
        try {
            # Comienza la transacción
            DB::connection( 'DbSolicitudesServicio' )->beginTransaction();
            # Localizamos la clave de cada uno del los usuarios o se crean
            $oUsuario = SSAcessos::firstOrCreate(
                [ 'TblDGP_id' => ( (int) request('TblDGP_id') ) ],
                [
                    'Clave' => rand(1000, 9999),
                    'Estatus' => 1,
                ]
            );
            /*
            $oUsuario = SSAcessos::where( 'TblDGP_id', request('TblDGP_id') )
                ->first();
            if ( is_null( $oUsuario ) ) {

                $oUsuario = SSAcessos::create([
                    'TblDGP_id' =>  request('TblDGP_id'),
                    'Clave' => rand(1000, 9999),
                    'Estatus' => 1,
                ]);

                $oUsuario = new SSAcessos;
                $oUsuario->TblDGP_id =  request('TblDGP_id');
                $oUsuario->Clave = rand(1000, 9999);
                $oUsuario->Estatus = 1;
                $oUsuario->save()
            }
            */
            #
            if ( optional( $oUsuario )->Clave == request( 'Pass' ) ) {
                return redirect()->route( 'servicios.solicitudes.asignaciones.tablero.show', request('TblDGP_id') );
            }else{
                return redirect()
                    ->back()
                    ->withInput()
                    ->withErrors( [ 'La contraseña no coincide' ] );
            }

            # Compromete las consultas
            DB::connection( 'DbSolicitudesServicio' )->commit();
        } catch( \Exception $e ) {
            # Rollback y luego redirigir volver al formulario con errores
            DB::connection( 'DbSolicitudesServicio' )->rollBack();
            \Log::debug( 'SolicitudesTableroController@store' );
            \Log::debug( $e );
            return redirect()
                ->back()
                ->withInput()
                ->withErrors( [ Str::limit( $e, 150, '...' ) ] );
        }
```

Comment: El código va como texto por favor. Ve que antes de la consulta abrís una transacción. Como la confirmás para que la query se ejecute?

Comment: ya lo actualicé, lo coloqué dentro de una try para capturar un posible error.

Comment: @GustavoDiazSalazar Tienes un IF antes de terminar la transacción. Creo que nunca llegas al commit.

Comment: el try lo agregué para comprobar si cargaba algún error que no detectara, pero no lo realiza por ninguno de los 3 métodos, lo extraño es que el apuntador del index de la BD si se incrementa; es decir, lo ejecuto sin resultado, pero paso el query y el ID no es x+1 sino x+2